# Is there a way to bulk change meta data on files?

Tags: windows, audio, metadata

I have a bunch of music. My files have the correct name. 'Mozart - Lacrimosa' but when I right click on the file and go to properties, the title is set to 'mozart_kv_626_lacrimosa' and I have hundreds of other files like this. So they fail to grab the meta data. Is there a way I can bulk change the 'title' metadata tag to match what I've renamed the file name to? Looking for something that I can just say "for each file, get filename and set as title"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of programs available to do what you are asking. My recommendation is to make a copy of a number of files you want to edit and try out the program before making the changes to all of your files.

[ID3 Renamer](https://www.id3renamer.com) (from their bulletpoints)

- Do you have loads of MP3 files in a directory and need to write a
  single common piece of information into them (e.g. the interpret or
  the album name)? You can type it in there manually, but this won't
  make you very cheerful if the amount of files is large.
- Using ID3 renamer, everything is a matter of a few mouse clicks. Do you need to
  clean some portion of the ID3 tag? Use ID3 renamer and don't erase
  like every single line.

[MP3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/)

- Batch Tag Editing Write ID3v1.1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, MP4, WMA, APEv2 Tags and Vorbis Comments to multiple files at once.

[List of other tools](https://www.lifewire.com/free-tools-for-editing-song-information-2438490)